# Unable to access CreateAsync in User Manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to use the new `Asp.Net Identity` system. I've searched this in asp.net site and able to find a tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity).

I've created `Register` action and appropriate view for it. But Unable to code it further as I'm struck using `User Manager` in Identity System.

To be precise, It's here.

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, register.Password);
```

The `UserManager` class throws an exception

```
Using the generic type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser,TKey>' requires 2 type arguments
```

My question is why did the author of the tutorial did not get any sort of exceptions ? Am I missing any dependencies ?

It seems like the documentation is not so perfect in asp.net site as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, register.Password);
```

The `UserManager` in the above statement is not a `Class` as I've expected. Its a property of type `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`.

So, at the beginning just declared a property as

```
public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
```

And now I can use the `Async` version for creating users. The following statement works.

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, register.Password);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you referenced "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0"?

[Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Core 2.0.0](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0)

**Update 1**
I've just looked back at some code where I have done this, and it looks like I ended up using the non-async version:

```
var result = userManager.Create(user, password);
```

Although this doesn't answer your specific question, it may help.

**Update 2**
Check you have the following using statements:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
```

Comment: Yes, I've also added Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin

Answer (score 0):

So, at the beginning just declared a property as

```
 public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get{return _userManager;} private set{} }
```

And

```
  private AppUserManager _userManager 
{
  get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();}
}
```