# How to create ApplicationUser by UserManager in Seed method of ASP .NET MVC 5 Web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, seed, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I can create users in the old way:

```
 var users = new List<ApplicationUser> { 
                        new ApplicationUser{PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword("TestPass44!"), Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl", UserName = "informatyka4444@wp.pl",  SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                        new ApplicationUser{PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword("TestPass44!"), Email = "informatyka4445@wp.pl", UserName = "informatyka4445@wp.pl",  SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}
                        };

users.ForEach(user => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(user));

context.SaveChanges();
```

but I want to do it the ASP.NET MVC 5.1 way using `UserManager`. I peeked how the `Register` POST method looks in `AccountController`:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded) { [...]
```

so I tried do the same:

```
var user =  new ApplicationUser() { Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl", 
                                    UserName = "informatyka4444@wp.pl"};
IdentityResult result =  UserManager.CreateAsync(user, "abcwq12312!P");
```

but I get this:

[image]

also If I just type `UserManager.` VS2013 does not shows any methods on the list.

So how to add user in this way?

EDIT1:

[image]

Comment: Is there any special reason that you want to user the **UserManager** class? Normally I would give the advice to use the context in the *Seed* method (and not the Identity stuff - there's no benefit of its asynchronous methods during the seeding of the database) and the Identity framework in the rest of the application (without any usage of the context).

Comment: @Horizon_Net I want to learn how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to access CreateAsync in User Manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081586/unable-to-access-createasync-in-user-manager)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok so to create user `CreateAsync` is unnecessary the problem was somewhere else. One should use `ApplicationUserManager` not `UserManager`(this one did not add anything to the database).

```
 var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
 var manager =  new ApplicationUserManager(store);
 var user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl", UserName = "informatyka4444@wp.pl" };
 manager.Create(user, "TestPass44!");
```

Comment: Hi @Yoda, please explain the value of context used in above code "var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context)" .
Thanks

Comment: I used the UserManager in the seed method without issues.  Just make sure you check for the result.Succeeded = true.  If nothing is saved to the database, you might be getting weak password errors.

Comment: You're a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

I dont understand the error you are showing, unless you are providing a custom `TUser` or `TKey` in which case would be like :

```
IdentityResult user = await UserManager.CreateAsync<CustomUser, CustomKey>(user, "abcwq12312!P");
```

and passing user as your `CustomUser` instead of `ApplicationUser` and maybe int if your `CustomKey` is an int instead of string. (CreateAsync can infer types, I posted there to show them explicitly)

The other problem I see is you are not awaiting the task, you must also add await like :

```
IdentityResult user = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, "abcwq12312!P");
```

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT:**

For completeness I will post the full answer from this question but there is your answer. : [Unable to access CreateAsync in User Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081586/unable-to-access-createasync-in-user-manager)

> ```
> var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, register.Password);
> ```
>
> The `UserManager` in the above statement is not a `Class` as I've
>   expected. Its a property of type `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`.
>
> So, at the beginning just declared a property as
>
> ```
> public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
> ```
>
> And now I can use the `Async` version for creating users. The
>   following statement works.
>
> ```
> var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, register.Password);
> ```

I will also flag for possible duplicate.

Comment: Tried that before please look at edit in OP. I also added async in method description.

Comment: After better research, I think here is your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081586/unable-to-access-createasync-in-user-manager

Comment: I posted the answer. Thank you for your help.